# What's wrong with "One of my children's name IS John"?

Tags: grammatical-number, saxon-genitive

Please don't throw this one out as a duplicate of [“one of …” singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/293406/one-of-singular-or-plural) I'm not asking about the plurality of the noun immediately following those two words - I'm interested in *exactly why* the example below is problematic (context: I have several children, one named John)...

> 1: *One of my children's name is John.*

I can't see any obvious *reason* why singular ***name*** there is completely unacceptable, but it certainly doesn't sit well with me. It seems to turn on whether ***one of my children*** can be treated collectively as the "subject" of the Saxon genitive **'s**, but I don't see a problem with...

> 2: *It's actually one of my children's, but you can sleep in this bed.*

I realise that in practice we'd normally pluralise ***names*** in the first example. But of course, this implies that ***one of*** attaches to ***my children's names***, which isn't really the same construction.

So - is there some kind of "rule, principle" debarring #1 above? Or is it just "one of those things"?

---

(Apologies if my later switch from *brothers* to *children* invalidates any comments or answers.)

Comment: @Davo You can't say that. It's “one of (my cousins’ houses)” and not “(one of my cousins)’s houses”.

Comment: If you need to distinguish, use a Romance genitive: _a house of my cousin's_ does the job nicely. That's one of the reasons we have two ways to do it.

Comment: @John: Perhaps I should have stuck to ***children*** thoughout, to avoid the confusion between plural **s** and genitive **'s**. But I still can't see exactly why I can't transform *the name of one of my children* into *one of my children's name*, even though I'm fully prepared to do this every time. Are there any closely-related contexts where I (or at least, *some* people) would be prepared to accept **'s** "collectively" modifying a compound subject of the general form ***one of X**?*

Comment: It seems to me that ***my brothers' name(s)*** is a thing...  and it's either _my brother**s'** names_ or _my brothe**r's** name_.  For the latter, you can't have a singular item with _one of_, because there is only one.  If you're going to say _one of_, it must be a plural set as in _my brother**s'** name**s**_.  If you want to avoid it, as others have mentioned, separate _name_ from the set that you're picking _one of_ -- _one of my brothers is named..._  In this case, the set of things that you're picking one of is your brothers and then you go on to discuss that.

Comment: To me "my brothers' name" connotes a name they all share. A common surname, for example.

Comment: @Roger Sinasohn: I've added explicit context, because it seems to me you're talking about *the name of my brother*, but I'm asking about *the name of **one of** my brothers*.

Comment: **One of my children is named/called John** seems to me the most natural, which I now see echos Roger Sinasohn's comment.

Comment: Similar/same problem as '* one of my shoe is on the floor*.

Comment: I think the confusion -- at least to me -- is are we talking about _(one of my children)'s name_ or are we talking about _one of (my children's names)_?  That is, are we selecting _one of the names (of my children)_ or are we selecting _one of my children (and discussing their name)_?

Comment: @Roger: That's what I meant when I said we usually pluralise ***names***, which implies that ***one of*** attaches to ***my children's names***, rather than being part of the "singular" NP ***one of my children*** to which we could in theory attach the possessive marker **'s** followed by the singular ***name*** (which would *seem* logical, since that one child only has one name).

Comment: @Clare: I don't see the connection. I'm not asking about the validity of ***one of my child*** as a noun phrase (which clearly *isn't* valid, since ***one of X*** logically requires that X be plural).

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- it's seems to me that it's completely ambiguous and, really, there's no way to tell, even from context, whether you're talking about the **name** of one of your children or a specific one of the set of **names** of your children.  I think either one is correct.  But I will defer to the opinion of experts...

Comment: @Roger: I did think about extending my "context" to include the fact that each child has only one (fore)name. Perhaps because we the parents belong to a social group that discourages multiple forenames for some oddball ideological reason - and the addressee knows this, so it's contextually implicit. But it seemed like a lot of contrived context, so I didn't bother.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I have three kids: Jared, Sara, and Ezra.  "My children" represents the three of them.  "My children's names" is the set of {Jared, Sara, Ezra}.  "One of my children" represents one of {the first born, the middle one, or the youngest} and that selection has a name, singular.  So, from that point of view, it would be _one of my children's name_ because "one of my children" represents, say, _the firstborn_ and thus we'd have _the firstborn's name_.  ...

Comment: But if we're referring to the set of names and selecting one of those, then it's like saying _one of {Jared, Sara, Ezra}_ and that set is clearly plural, so it would be _one of {my children's names}_.

Comment: @Roger: You've certainly summarised the alternative parsings more eloquently than me. But the fact of the matter is we *don't* use the "singular" version (even though it sorta makes sense), and I'm trying to get a handle on exactly *why* this is so.

Comment: I can't back this up with anything but personal experience, but I think one of the main driving forces for humans is laziness.  With the singular version, the reader/listener starts of with "one of" and then gets to "name" and has to stop because "hey, I thought this was about _one of_ something!"  So they have to go back and figure out that _one of_ applies to "my children" and not the name(s).  It's a lot less work to parse "my children's names" as a set and then apply the _one of_ to it.  At least, that's how I'd view it.  (And I am nothing if not lazy.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this construction seems to be be attested in some documents indexed by Google Books:

> The Witness: One of my children's name is Richard White.

(*[The federal reporter](https://books.google.com/books?id=O9g3AAAAIAAJ&q=%22of%20my%20children's%20name%22&dq=%22of%20my%20children's%20name%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrjOruveHUAhUl9IMKHeAkCHQQ6AEIQTAF)* - Volume 219 - Page 170)

> Yes, but prior to that time it was in one of my children's name, prior to that time, I think [...]

(*[Records and Briefs in Cases Decided by the Supreme Court of Minnesota](https://books.google.com/books?id=qJBKAQAAMAAJ&q=%22of%20my%20children's%20name%22&dq=%22of%20my%20children's%20name%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCqMzQvuHUAhWm7YMKHTHwBLk4ChDoAQgtMAI),* 1907)

Of course, this is just an interesting fact; by itself, it doesn't answer your question. These could be simple production errors (which are common in speech), or it could be that the speakers quoted here had internalized different grammatical rules than you did. (Or these could even be transcription errors!) We still have to explain why you find this sort of sentence unacceptable.

---

Unfortunately, I don't know the relevant rule making it ungrammatical. But I do think I can explain why you judge sentence 2 to be grammatical.

I think in your sentence 2, the word "one" is, or at least seems like it can be, interpreted to refer to a bed rather than a child.

> 2: It's actually one of my children's, but you can sleep in this bed.

"This bed is actually one of [my children's beds], but you can sleep in it"

This means much the same thing as a hypothetical "*This bed is [one of my children's] bed" would, so it's hard to notice the difference in implied structure when only the elided form is used. However, I think the second structure would actually be ungrammatical, just as you say "*One of my children's name is John" is ungrammatical.

At first, I thought it might have something to do with the indefiniteness, but "a child's name" is acceptable, and "the youngest of my children's name" doesn't seem fully acceptable (although I might be imagining that it sounds slightly better than "one of my children's name").

Personally, I feel a bit uneasy with using *'s*-genitives after phrases that end in plural nouns no matter what the internal structure  of the noun phrase is. "[The queen of England's crown](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92506/the-queen-of-englands-crown-or-the-queens-of-england-crown)" sounds OK to me, but "The queen of the mice's crown" less so. I think a relevant point is whether "The father of my children's name" sounds any more or less acceptable to you.

I think the "clitic" nature of the English possessive *-'(s)* construction is somewhat exaggerated in the kind of short explanations that we provide on this site: there are definite complications and restrictions concerning its use (which I know have been analyzed in linguistic literature, but I am not familar enough with it to say more than that). Wikipedia has a short overview of some relevant analyses: [Status of the possessive as a grammatical case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive#Status_of_the_possessive_as_a_grammatical_case).

"Also, here is an interesting paper I found: [The English “Group Genitive” is a Special Clitic](https://cowgill.ling.yale.edu/sra/elsj.pdf)", Stephen R. Anderson

Comment: I found [Some of the children's **father** may be in jail, some don't even know the children's **father,** and some of the children's **fathers** may be hopeless or useless](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22children%27s+father+may+be+in+jail+some%22) in Google Books. I suppose there's some "logic" to the choices made there (I don't *think* it's necessarily a couple of "typos"), but it's definitely a bit disconcerting (much more disconcerting than the one in your "special clitic" link: *Even that attractive young man who is trying to flirt with you’s taste in wallpaper is appalling.)*

Answer (score 1):

My musing: We have inventory of possible constructs we expect to hear after a sentence-initial "One of my brothers'" (or, indeed, "One of my children's"). But the usage you're asking about isn't common, so it isn't part of that inventory, or else it's in the inventory but assigned a low priority. After hearing or reading "One of my children's", we have already mapped out in our heads a likely structure for the sentence, a "garden path" situation. When the next word doesn't fit that structure, it leads to confusion and dissonance.

Therefore, it's better to stick with "The name of one of my children is John" or "One of my children is named John".

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the span of "one of" is usually read to apply to the noun "name" as opposed to "children" which is used as part of an adjective phrase.  So, I would expect the sentence to read "One of my children's names" instead.