# Singular vs plural after "One example of such"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

In sentences like "One example of such `X` is `Y`" should `X` be singular, plural or can it be either?

For example:

> Some methods are {description of this group of methods}. 
> One example of such **methods** is the {name of some specific method}.

Is this grammatically correct? Or should it be "one example of such a **method**" since we are talking about a singular example?

Another example:

> These utilities form a significant portion of {...}. 
> One example of such **a utility** is a water cooling system.

I think, I've seen both singular and plural versions in fairly respectable sources, but now I'm having doubts if both are valid.

Here is a [very similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/293406/one-of-singular-or-plural), but I'm not sure if similar reasoning applies here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are often grammatical. The logical form (bolding mine):

> - One example of such **differences** in regulatory treatment is the Standardised Approach in the CRR, which applies lower risk weights to
>   certain ...

[[Bank of England / European Central Bank](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/pdf/other/ecb-boe_case_better_functioning_securitisation_marketen.pdf)]

(Compare 'Such differences in regulatory treatment are known to exist; one example is the Standardised Approach in the CRR'.)

Many such examples are to be found in a Google search for "one example of such" -"one example of such a"

...............

But the 'distributive singular' may also be used:

> - Mass phishing campaigns are one example of such **an attack**.

[[HM Government](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/crowded-places-guidance/cyber-security)]

> - [O]ne example of such **a risk** would be dangerous electrical installations or wiring.

[[Bath and North East Somerset: Essential Information for Landlords and Agents](https://www.bathnes.gov.uk/sites/default/files/sitedocuments/Housing/Landlords-and-tenants/essential_information_for_landlords_and_agents.pdf)]

Again, many such examples are to be found in Google searches for "one example of such a" / "one example of such an".

Answer (score 0):

"One example of such a utility is a water cooling system."

This is correct. You are talking about one, so using the plural of utility (utilities) would be wrong.

Comment: Can you provide some more justification? I've seen cases, where a plural is used in such sentences. For eaxmple: here's [a wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality) that uses "methods", [this paper abstract](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B978012385977800007X) uses "plasmas". Are these grammatical errors?